# Create a text file in Gdrive using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

I am doing a web app using javascript and j query.
I want to take notes from a input text field from my web page and want to save that content in a text file on Gdrive.
I am able to sign in and authorize the user but cant able to save that content to gdrive.
Can any body help me, how to create a file using javascript, or how to upload it to g drive.

I am following the google drive sdk documentation.
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

These methods are used to upload a file to gdrive from local machine. I dont have a file.
I have a variable which is a string of words. i want to save them as a text file in g drive.

```
 /**
       * Start the file upload.
       *
       * @param {Object} evt Arguments from the file selector.
       */
      function uploadFile(evt) {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
          var file = evt.target.files[0];
          insertFile(file);
        });
      }

      /**
       * Insert new file.
       *
       * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
       * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
       */
      function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
        const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
          var metadata = {
            'title': fileData.name,
            'mimeType': contentType
          };

          var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
          var multipartRequestBody =
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
              JSON.stringify(metadata) +
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
              'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
              '\r\n' +
              base64Data +
              close_delim;

          var request = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
              'method': 'POST',
              'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
              'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
              },
              'body': multipartRequestBody});
          if (!callback) {
            callback = function(file) {
              console.log(file)
            };
          }
          request.execute(callback);
        }
      }
```

Thankyou.

Comment: what does your existing code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

```
/**
 * Insert new file.
 *
 * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
 * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    var metadata = {
      'title': fileData.fileName,
      'mimeType': contentType
    };

    var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        base64Data +
        close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
        'method': 'POST',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody});
    if (!callback) {
      callback = function(file) {
        console.log(file)
      };
    }
    request.execute(callback);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx. can you explain what is happning in this code. I think this code is for uploading a file . I have a string. How can i save that to g drive.

Comment: The line that says " base64Data +" is the string of text that you want to upload.

Comment: hey @pinoyyid thanx now i am able to create file in g drive but  'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + i gave content type= text/plain , but my text is not coming properly in the file i think it is encoded , can you help me in this.